# Asp.Net Core SSL with nginx on Ubuntu 18

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I configure asp.net core webapi to use ssl certificate with nginx as reverse proxy on Ubuntu 18?

I am able to run without https.

I tried creating a self signed cert, but got stuck on how to configure the nginx.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to use nginx as reverse proxy and how to configure a certificate there is clearly off-topic, and belong to ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices, you can create self-cert to NginX or you can create self-cert to your application.
I think so that the options more easy is create self-cert to nginx from ubuntu.

Don´t forget about config server in default file nginx.

Follow this link:

[How to create self cert NginX](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04)